# Выбор значения элемента select и подставить в тег input

Tags: javascript

Есть выпадающий список (select) и текстовое поле (input) в одной форме. При выборе элемента из select я получаю его значение. И это значение нужно вставить в input.

Например, при выборе третьего элемента select надо вставить его значение вместо 'some value', а в остальных случаях оставить как есть.

Вот код:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Первый</option>
  <option value="2">Второй</option>
  <option value="3">Третий</option>
</select>

<input name="numbs" value="some value">
```

JS:

```
$("select").change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == 3) {
      // alert($(this).val());
   }    
});
```

Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: `$('input[name="numbs"]').val($(this).val())`

Comment: @mix спасибо, можете написать как ответ я его отмечу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("select").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 3) {
        $('input[name="numbs"]').val($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: те же условия но теперь надо сделать тег input disabled с пустым value

Comment: @Xfirab `$('input[name="numbs"]').val('').prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: mix все отлично, но в IE6 почему то не срабатывает записать disabled, что посоветуете, кроме удаления IE6 ))

Comment: @Xfirab для IE6 я не пишу, посему однозначно ответить на ваш вопрос не могу, нужно пробовать варианты. Попробуйте, как вариант, написать данный код на нативном js `setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")`

Comment: можете написать на нативном JS, я просто плохо знаю JS

Comment: вместо `.prop` добавьте `.get(0).setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")`, для проверки, сработает ли